# Substrate node template fees deduction using native token

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node

I have create blockchain using substrate-node-template with aura consensus and which contains own native coin and I have created `stable-coin` using `pallet-contract`. This stable token is `contract`, whenever the transaction occurs between two parties using stable-token, I want to convert the transaction fees from stable token to native coin on flow. Is it possible and if there is any example implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation is using the native token.

You should revert your stable-coin changes.

Balances is the native token pallet.

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/700c3a186e55d0d6542c564ccff17260238ed752/runtime/src/lib.rs#L283

And pass it to transaction payment's `CurrencyAdapter`.

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/700c3a186e55d0d6542c564ccff17260238ed752/runtime/src/lib.rs#L254

That's it.